# Android detect keyboard hide in landscape mode

Tags: android, keyboard, hide, visible

Using the method shown in this thread - [How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)

I am able to detect keyboard hide when in portrait mode or in landscape mode where the keyboard is not in fullscreen. If keyboard in landscape mode is fullscreen then, the layout changes are not triggered and hence i cannot detect it in the **OnGlobalLayoutListener** !

Please help me with this? Is there no simple way to detect keyboard hide?

**NOTE:** I cannot afford to change anything in the manifest file. It should all be done through code dynamically!

Thanks!